# on my SharePoint local Workbench, the ribbon won't show up and I don't know why

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm currently working with the local SharePoint workbench and it looks a little weird, because the ribbon with the text SharePoint Workbench is not visible and I don't know why.

I hope that you can help me. It's just a visual problem, but I appreciate your help.

Attached is a screenshot in Chrome.[image]

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Not to derail your thread, but the local workbench is deprecated - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.12.0#deprecations-and-removed-items-in-this-release

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading to SPFX 1.12, then this should be a change in SPFX V1.12 as Local Workbench deprecated, it's the same with me:

[image]